# Debug Logs - how to download data

Tags: community, debug, debug-logs

I want to dowload data which contains debug logs. Is it saving somewhere in files or Database column, from where I can read it? 
My idea is to stream data from there to my app, which is looking for a specified action (simple regex etc...). I want any clues, cause i couldnt find it anywhere (also in db, but maybe some of you have met with similiar issue).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not talking about portal logs but regular debug logs,then simply go to
developer console > logs > there you will see multiple logs(Recent log on top) >
right click > download logs